# How can i make the player idle when not moving the mouse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When i'm moving the mouse around the player is walking facing to the mouse cursor.
Now i want to make that if i'm not moving the mouse to make the player idle.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WorldInteraction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed = 5; // Determines how quickly object moves towards position
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;
    private Animator _animator;
    private bool toMove = true;
    private Vector3 tmpMousePosition;

    UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent playerAgent;

    private void Start()
    {
        tmpMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _animator.CrossFade("Idle", 0);

        playerAgent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && toMove == false &&
  !UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) 
       {
            toMove = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && toMove == true)
        {
            toMove = false;
        }
        if (toMove == true)
        {
            GetInteraction();
        }
    }

    void GetInteraction()
    {

        if (tmpMousePosition != Input.mousePosition)
        {
            tmpMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
            _animator.CrossFade("Walk", 0);
            Ray interactionRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit interactionInfo;
            if (Physics.Raycast(interactionRay, out interactionInfo, Mathf.Infinity))
            {
                GameObject interactedObject = interactionInfo.collider.gameObject;
                if (interactedObject.tag == "Interactable Object")
                {
                    interactedObject.GetComponent<Interactable>().MoveToInteraction(playerAgent);
                }
                else
                {
                    playerAgent.destination = interactionInfo.point;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _animator.CrossFade("Idle", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the variable tmpMousePosition to check if the mouse is in a move or not. The problem is when it's on a move and the player is in "Walk" mode the player is stuttering each a second or so.

The idea is when the mouse is moving then move the player when the mouse is not moving make the player in Idle.

In the Update function i'm using a bool to stop/continue the interaction like a switch with the mouse left/right buttons. But now i want to use the mouse movement to Walk/Idle the player.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is; simply compare the mouse position between frames to see whether the mouse is moving or not (may have to be more complicated if you want to have a cooldown period once the mouse stops) and then only move if the position has changed. What am I missing?

Comment: If the mouse hasn't moved or clicked, increment a timer by `deltaTime` when it reaches 30 (or however many seconds) *then* the player's idle. If the mouse DID move, reset the timer to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the movement through `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` and if it's not moving , play Idle